# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException in Flume Kafka Sink

Tags: apache-kafka, flume-ng

I am trying to read data from JMS source and pushing them into KAFKA topic, while doing that after few hours i observed that pushing frequency to the KAFKA topic became almost zero and after some initial analysis i found following exception in FLUME logs .

```
28 Feb 2017 16:35:44,758 ERROR [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run:158)  - Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: Failed to publish events
        at org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink.process(KafkaSink.java:252)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:67)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:145)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 1399305 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$FutureFailure.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:686)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:449)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink.process(KafkaSink.java:212)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 1399305 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.
```

my flume shows the current set value (in logs ) for  max.request.size as 1048576 , which is clearly very less than  1399305 , increasing this max.request.size may eliminate these exception but am unable to find correct place for updating that value .

My flume.config ,

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.channels = c1
a1.sinks = k1

a1.channels.c1.type = file
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 100000000
a1.channels.c1.checkpointDir = /data/flume/apache-flume-1.7.0-bin/checkpoint
a1.channels.c1.dataDirs = /data/flume/apache-flume-1.7.0-bin/data

a1.sources.r1.type = jms

a1.sources.r1.interceptors.i1.type = timestamp
a1.sources.r1.interceptors.i1.preserveExisting = true

a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.initialContextFactory = some context urls
a1.sources.r1.connectionFactory = some_queue
a1.sources.r1.providerURL = some_url 
#a1.sources.r1.providerURL = some_url
a1.sources.r1.destinationType = QUEUE
a1.sources.r1.destinationName = some_queue_name 
a1.sources.r1.userName = some_user
a1.sources.r1.passwordFile= passwd

a1.sinks.k1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.topic = some_kafka_topic
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = some_URL
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.acks = 1
a1.sinks.k1.flumeBatchSize = 1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Any help will be really appreciated !!

Answer (score 4):

This change has to be done at Kafka.
Update the Kafka producer configuration file `producer.properties` with a larger value like

```
max.request.size=10000000
```

Comment: I am using FLUME where it uses producer lib of KAFKA to push the messages on Topics , but i cant see it as configurable iin FLUME ; Do i need to change any hard coded value into producer classes ?

Comment: @RiteshSharma Are you saying that you do not have Kafka installed on the server?

Comment: Actually this "max.request.size" issue is coming for FLUME where am using kafka sink to push data on kafka brokers , so basically FLUME uses kafka producer libraries (kafka sink) to push data on kafka brokers ; FLUME doesn't provide any dedicated configuration file as "producer.properties" you need to update kafka producer properties in FLUME configuration only .

Comment: Yes, Flume uses Kafka. So my solution was to change this property at Kafka level, as the property `max.request.size` belongs to kafka producer, which in turn be applied for Flume!

Comment: Yeah , Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like i have resolved my issue ; As suspected increasing the `max.request.size` eliminated the exception , for updating such kafka sink(producer) properties FLUME provides the constant prefix as `kafka.producer`. and we can append this constant prefix with any kafka properties ;

so mine goes as, `a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.max.request.size = 5271988` .

Comment: Wow. Never knew this is possible!